# Why ASUS RT-AC3200 continues to accept connections from the WAN to the administration site, even if this has been turned off?

Tags: networking, router

Monitoring my home router RT-AC3200 (Firmware Version:3.0.0.4.382_50624) during the last couple of days, I have been seeing continuos attempts to login from the WAN to the administration console. Already disabled Remote Access Config, but still the admin log continues to show attempts. 
Any ideas?

Attached are the Screenshot[Disabled remote access to config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2zxZ.jpg) and [log from the administration tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n0FaA.jpg)

Comment: After you save the configuration, have you tried to reboot the router, to confirm the settings were saved?

Comment: Yes the router was rebooted and the setting maintained

Comment: The only way you can verify if it's actually disabled, is to attempt to log into the router remotely yourself, using and authenticate as a user that exists.  If it allows you to remotely access your configuration page, you know the firmware, has a bug in it.  If it gives you an error page about the functionality being disabled you have confirmed the logs are normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have done all that is necessary according to the manual.

I would think that disabling the Web administration will not stop the reports
on *attempts* to login to your router. Reporting them should be a necessary
security feature, so you can know that you are under attack.

From your screenshot, I think that you may add an additional security layer by
also setting "Allow only speciﬁed IP address" to some impossible IP address.

For security, you might also reboot the router to ensure that the setting
is kept, just in case a power outage may cause it to reboot.

Comment: Thanks will add the specific IP. My expectation was that the router would not even respond to the WAN requests to connect to the admin console, but anyways makes sense continue reporting